# Should I run Glue crawler everytime to fetch latest data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-spark

I have a S3 bucket named Employee. Every three hours I will be getting a file in the bucket with a timestamp attached to it. I will be using Glue job to move the file from S3 to Redshift with some transformations. My input file in S3 bucket will have a fixed structure. My Glue Job will use the table created in Data Catalog via crawler as the input.

First run:

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "test", table_name = "employee_623215", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
```

After three hours if I am getting one more file for employee should I crawl it again?

Is there a way to have a single table in Data Catalog like employee and update the table with the latest S3 file which can be used by Glue Job for processing. Or should I run crawler every time to get the latest data? The issue with that is more number of tables will be created in my Data Catalog.

Please let me know if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach can be, instead of reading from catalog read directly from s3 and process data in Glue job.

This way you need not to run crawler again.

Use

> from_options(connection_type, connection_options={}, format=None, format_options={}, transformation_ctx="")

Documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-reader.html)

Comment: Hi Shubham, my incoming file will have a timestamp to it. If I have to use it from S3 directly I need to change the file name everytime in Glue job which wont be ideal for production environment. Please let me know if this is the case.

Comment: You need to provide the path to folder only not the file name to be precise

Comment: How should we handle this with multiple files?

Comment: Hi @HaryS does the solution marked by you works fine ? I am wondering because i am having same problem and followed the solution but it didnt' work as new partition and files are not correctly detected by the glue job

Answer (score 4):

You only need to run the AWS Glue Crawler again if the schema changes. As long as the schema remains unchanged, you can just add files to Amazon S3 without having to re-run the Crawler.

Update: @Eman's comment below is correct

> If you are reading from catalog this suggestion will not work. Partitions will not be updated to the catalog table if you do not recrawl. Running the crawler maps those new partitions to the table and allow you to process the next day's partitions.

Comment: Hi Dennis,

On the first day my glue job code will have the following input:

First run: datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "test", table_name = "employee", transformation_ctx = "datasource0") ( first day data)

Second day I will be getting a new data in S3 bucket if I use this in glue job code datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "test", table_name = "employee", transformation_ctx = "datasource0") wont it have the earlier day's data?

Please let me now!

Comment: If you are reading from catalog this suggestion will not work. Partitions will not be updated to the catalog table if you do not recrawl. Running the crawler maps those new partitions to the table and allow you to process the next day's partitions.